# How to use await on methods in interfaces

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

When implementing against an interface (because of mocking, remoting or similiar) using the *await* keyword and having an interface with methods returning Task<> :

```
interface IFoo
{
    Task<BigInteger> CalculateFaculty(int value);
}
```

the compiler comes up with an error:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

Which is a bit unusual considering the return type is "Task". This problem is kind of frustrating and forces me to "fall back" using *continuation style* or providing an extra proxy around this interface (and therefore for almost every interface which is not really feasible for me)

Does anyone have a good idea on how to solve this?

Comment: what is the code that gives an error? Surely not the interface declaration...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interfaces and async methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573516/interfaces-and-async-methods)

Comment: Meanwhile I've extended my async/await knowledge "a bit" and the key thing here to understand is: "await" is a compiler tool that asks the compiler to rewrite a method that is written in a "synchronous" into an "asynchronous callback" style. "async" just marks a method for being allowed to contain "await"s (plus deals with the return value). So the keywords don't make sense on a pure method signature (method without body) like in an interface definition as there is nothing for the compiler to rewrite. Again: From a caller's perspective async/await are  not relevant. Returning a Task counts.

Comment: This seems like something they should fix. Why should an interface not explictly specify implementations shouldn't be async? An interface is just a list of signatures. If it impacts how you call a method (which it does in the concrete method), the interface should know about it. Seems like one of those cases when being a purist goes against commonsense.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The message is not about the interface, but about the calling method. You need to mark the method containing the `await` keyword with the `async` modifier:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Task<int> AwaitableMethod();
}

class Bar
{
    static async Task AsyncMethod() // marked as async!
    {
        IFoo x;
        await x.AwaitableMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shame on me. You are totally right and the error states what's wrong quite clearly. I just kept misreading it in the context of the interface method instead of the method calling the interface method. Thank you!

Comment: This is not a good example, because `Main()` can't be `async`.

Comment: Well technically it's just another static method, so it CAN be async (the code I wrote compiled). Of course you're right in that it doesn't make much sense. Updated my answer...

Answer (score 12):

This must be ok:

```
interface IFoo
{
    Task<BigInteger> CalculateFaculty(int value);
}

public class Foo: IFoo
{
  public async Task<BigInteger> CalculateFaculty(int value)
  {
    var res =  await AsyncCall();
    return res;
  }
}
```

---

usage:

```
 public async Task DoSomething(IFoo foo) 
 { 
   var result = await foo.CalculateFaculty(123); 
 }
```

Comment: I am just curious:  Wouldn't it be better to rename the method to CalculateFacultyAsync then ?   I am new to Async/Await and according to the MSDN the name should indicate the async behaviour.

Comment: There are different options around.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler message is not on the usage on the interface. It is an asynchronous request on a task that is implemented by the runtime when an appropriate await is encountered on the operation.

Usage should be on the method implementation ie. the class; the interface usage is the same as it would be for setters and getters in an interface.